# Non-polymorphic/Non-STI one-one relationship with activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Sorry if its a noob question but I could not find this in earlier posts.

Can I implement this with active record?

I have 3 tables `Branch`, `Person`, and `Address` with following relationships:

```
Branch.Address (one-one)
Person.Address (one-one)
```

I know from the documentation that this can be implemented as polymorphic association which maintains the FK (`addressable_id`) in `ADDRESS` table along with type info (`addressable_type=/Branch/|Person/`).

What I want to do is to have the `address_id` in both `Branch` and `Person` tables and keep `Address` as an independent table without any dependency on external tables. I would also like to retain the ability to control life cycle of the `address` object (cascade save/update/delete) from `Branch`/`Person` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to specify that Branch and Person `belongs_to` Address

```
class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :branch
  has_one :person
end
```

This will give you a method `#address` for both Branch and Person, and allow you to interact with it that way.

Comment: Josh, Thanks for the quick response. If I do this, do I not give has_one relationship in Address?

Comment: whoops, I missed that.  Putting the has_one is optional, only needed if you need to call address#person or addresss#branch.  I've added those now.

Comment: That will do. Thanks for the help Josh.